# how to compare two string variable using if condition in jsf

Tags: if-statement, jsf, jstl, el

```
<c:if test="#{active eq status }">
      <label class="switch">
          <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="input" id="sta" value="#{CMB.check}" />
          <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
</c:if>
```

i am trying to compare two variable but it is always returning false although varibles values are  equals

Comment: What is status? Is it the status variable from a JSF loop component like ui:repeat? If so, read this carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense